# Is it correct to use the word "excuse for" + "why"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me plase if it is correct to use *excuse for* with *why*. For example:

> He is constantly making **excuses for why** he is late.

If it is correct, then how is difference than the following sentence?

> He is constantly making excuses for being late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but not exactly right. the better expression is the second one 
you gave:

He is constantly making excuses for being late.

The excuses are 'why', so saying 'excuses for why' seems to add an unnecessary layer of reference.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and mean the same thing. "Excuses for why" is somewhat awkward and definitely verbose, but those defects are common in spontaneous speech because we seldom even try to edit and revise as we are talking. In writing, we can and frequently do edit and revise. Few good writers will **write**, whatever they **may sometimes say**, "excuses for why" because it is verbose.